# How to reverse the scroll movement?

Tags: jquery

I try to make a reverse navigation. I show the page from the bottom with scrollTo.
I want reverse the wheel movement, when the whell movement is down the page goes to the top.

The body has a fix height so I use:

```
 window.scrollTo(0, 2000);
```

Comment: How is that single line going to help you?

Comment: Hi Alon I know it. I try with some code but I don´t know how to make what I want. Only I show the way to show the page from the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Prevent the default [`wheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) event action and then  programmatically do the exact reverse of it using [`window.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) method. Where use [`deltaX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaX) and [`deltaY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaY) to get scroll amount and [`scrollX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollX) and [`scrollY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) positithe on to get current scroll position.

```js
document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  window.scrollTo(window.scrollX - e.deltaX, window.scrollY - e.deltaY)
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#div {
  height: 2000px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Check [polyfill for making stable across different browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel#Polyfill).

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work

Comment: @crismf :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel#Polyfill

Comment: @PranavCBalan It doesn't work on the `window` object on Chrome, I see lot's of errors referencing to [this](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312), but your solution does work on any other element in the DOM, so this answer works

Comment: @AlonEitan : ooops.... thanks mate.... let me update with body

Comment: @PranavCBalan can you show me a example? Can I use this solution maybe in a div?

Comment: @crismf :  please check now.... I'd updated with body tag

Comment: I have the same problem https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312 But thanks for your time and  code